# Gradle and IDEA disagree on where Kotlin source files should go

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

By default, IntelliJ IDEA puts Kotlin source files for package `foo` in `src/*.kt` but Gradle isn't happy with that; it can only see them if they go in `src/main/kotlin/foo/*.kt`.

I've tried moving them there, but now IDEA gives a warning in my source files, in the `package foo` line, saying 'package directive doesn't match file location' and wanting to change the package to `main.kotlin.foo` (which of course would be incorrect, and probably confuse Gradle again).

How do you get the two to agree on where the files should go? (Ideally I would like it to be somewhere that doesn't have any levels of empty subdirectories, but I will settle for anything the two programs can agree on.)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that if you just delete the IDEA configuration, IDEA will automatically rebuild it from the Gradle project, and thereby become happy with the Gradle default layout.